# Centering a video element with margin: 0 auto;

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I can't seem to center this video element in this page I've been messing around with:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <video id="vid" x-webkit-airplay="allow" controls width="640" height="360" src="http://ec2-184-72-239-149.compute-1.amazonaws.com:1935/demos/smil:bigbuckbunnyiphone.smil/playlist.m3u8"></video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#vid {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can view the code online [here at jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/VxCn6/) Why isn't my `<video>` element centering itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add a `display: block` to your `#vid`

Comment: to refresh my knowledge of `display` options: http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/SCvwV/

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
#vid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Its likely where the HTML5 spec isnt finished as im sure `<video>` would be a block or inline-block

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="vid"> <video id="vid" x-webkit-airplay="allow" controls width="640" height="360"
       src="http://ec2-184-72-239-149.compute-1.amazonaws.com:1935/demos/smil:bigbuckbunnyiphone.smil/playlist.m3u8"></video></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:640px;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to add an extra element.

Comment: Well, yeah. It just makes it block.